# URL is loading perfect in Chrome but not in FinestWebView

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I am using FinestWebView to load URL's in my app.
https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android

My URL is showing perfectly in Chrome browser but in FinestWebView, URL is not showing properly. It gets cut off half way. Bottom of the web page is not shown.

In Chrome:

[image]

In FinestWebView:

[image]

Please tell me which flags to enable/disable to get full screen.

Below is the code for loading URL:

```
new FinestWebView.Builder(context)
            .showUrl(false)
            .showIconMenu(false)
            .titleDefault(getString(R.string.payment))
            .updateTitleFromHtml(false)
            .iconDefaultColorRes(R.color.white_color)
            .show(urlPlan);
```

styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusBarColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/dark_green</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.thefinestartist.finestwebview.FinestWebViewActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"  />
```

Comment: Hi Varun ! I think you should remove `.iconDefaultColorRes(R.color.white_color)` from your code.

Comment: Hi Woods, this doesn't help at all. We have tried with basic layout, no customisation. Still it doesn't work.